# jQuery and HTML5 video - change source onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video

I have to create an interactive video using HTML5 and jQuery. My goal is to:

1. Play `video1`
2. When `video1` ends show `button1`, `onClick` change to `video2` and hide `button1`
3. Play `video2`
4. `On Ended` show `button 2`, `OnClick` change to `video 3`
5. and so on...

My question to you is, what am I doing wrong?
This is my code.

```
<section> 
<video autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" onended="testEnded()">
    <source id="srcWebm" src="media/Madagascar.webm"/>
</video>
</section>

<section id="buttons" class="btnShow">
    <ul id="buttons2" hidden>
        <li><a href="#" id="choice1" onclick="changeSrc1()">VW</a></li>

    </ul>
</section>
```

The function `testEnded()` is in an external sheet (which is linked properly to the html).
The script is as follows:

```
function changeSrc1() {
    $('#srcWebm').attr('src','media/VW.webm');

}

function testEnded() {
        $('#buttons2').removeAttr('hidden');
    }
```

When I execute `changeSrc1()` nothing happens. I have tried linting the code - no errors...

What should I do?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983036/how-do-you-change-video-src-using-jquery

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to make something similar work:

```
<video id="video" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">
 <source id="srcWebm" src="media/Madagascar.webm"/>
</video>

var video = document.getElementById("video"); 
video.src = "your link here";
```

However, this is currently giving me issues in IE9.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution: apparently, jQuery does not support changing the 'src' attribute of the `<source>`. Bug?

Answer (score 0):

than delete all children from `<video>`-tag, and create a new `<source>` element which you insert into the `<video>` node

Answer (score 0):

Check this plugin, it has some properties which can be useful for you.

Download Plugin

> http://videojs.com/

API Reference

> http://videojs.com/docs/api/

I hope it will help you.