# HTML 5 video switcher won't play in Safari or IE 9

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, dom-events

I've built out a very simple HTML 5 video switcher that works great in Firefox and Chrome. I can see the src values change, as desired, but there seems to be an issue with triggering the `load()` and/or `play()` events. I've gone as far as editing `.htaccess` to ensure the mime types and changed the paths to the videos to direct http links. I'm pretty sure the issues lies within how simple the load/play function is but am struggling trouble shooting this or finding reliable documentation online.

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var videos = new Array();

videos[0] = [
         "poster1.png",
         "video1.mp4",
         "video1.ogv"
         ];
videos[1] = [
         "poster2.png",
         "video2.mp4",
         "video2.ogv"
         ];
videos[2] = [
         "poster3.png",
         "video3.mp4",
         "video3.ogv"
         ];
videos[3] = [
         "poster4.png",
         "video4.mp4",
         "video4.ogv"
         ];

function switchVideo(n) {
    if (n >= videos.length) n = 0;

    var video = $("#video");
    var mp4 = $("#mp4");
    var ogv = $("#ogv");

    video.attr("poster", videos[n][0]);
    mp4.attr("src", videos[n][1]);
    ogv.attr("src", videos[n][2]);
    
    loadVid();
}

function loadVid() {
    document.getElementById("video").load();
    document.getElementById("video").play();
}
</script>

<div>
<video id="video" poster="poster1.png" height="445px" width="900px" preload>

  <source id="mp4" src="video1.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
  <source id="ogv"  src="video1.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
  
  <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>

</video><br>

  <button onClick="switchVideo(0);">Video 1</button>
  <button onClick="switchVideo(1);">Video 2</button>
  <button onClick="switchVideo(2);">Video 3</button>
  <button onClick="switchVideo(3);">Video 4</button>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you triggering the load and play events? Don't you want to do this instead? `document.getElementById("video").onload = function () { document.getElementById("video").play(); }`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken IE 9 requires that the `VIDEO` tag be 'created', so to speak, at the same time as the `SOURCE` tags. For example, using javascript `println` in chunks won't work, nor changing the value of the `SRC` attribute of `SOURCE`s. You might need to replace the whole `VIDEO` tag or have one for each video.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080433/unable-to-change-source-of-video-tag-via-javascript-on-ie9 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760143/jquery-and-html5-video-change-source-onclick